# Why stuck in the ubuntu 13.04 installation?

Tags: system-installation

When I install the ubuntu 13.04, It gets stuck in the "Processing triggers for update-notifier-common"?

It's been stuck at least 30 minutes.

I didn't choose the option "Download updates while installation ".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you restart your installation and choose the Download Update while installing option and see if it works then.

If that does not work then it might be an issue with your bootable device so just redownload the IO and remake/reburn your CD/flash drive.